# Arduino sprintf in println with F()

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

Hello I am having problems with my C code , I am trying to println(F(VARIABLE)) but I am getting an error

```
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    sendData(25,60);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:    
}

void sendData(float temperature,float batterylvl){
    char tmp[25];
    char batt[25];
    sprintf(tmp, "temperature=%f", temperature);
    sprintf(batt, "battery=%f", batterylvl);

    Serial.println(F(tmp));
    Serial.println(F(batt));      
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`F()` is for *constant strings*. Such as the format strings passed to `sprintf()`. Not like the variables passed to `Serial.println()`.